# @NamedNativeQuery Constraint violation - Transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, ejb

I have this @NamedNativeQuery

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "Certificacion.updateCertificacionAclaraciones", query = "UPDATE CERTIFICACION "
                + "SET PENDIENTE_GENERACION = :pendienteGeneracion, ID_ACLARACIONES_TEMP_ESCRITO = :idAclaracion "
                + "WHERE ID IN (:paso)")
```

And I have this EJB structure to get a transaction

```
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@Stateless
public class PRequerimientoCCServiceBean implements
        IPRequerimientoCCServiceBeanLocal {
    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
        public void guardarRequerimiento(Usuario usuario,
                ConjuntoCertificaciones conjunto, String aclaracionGeneral,
                Map<Long, String> mapAclaracionColegio) throws RollbackException {
            try {
                // Realizamos el guardado de las aclaraciones y la generación del
                // documento
                AclaracionesTempEscrito currentAclaracion = new AclaracionesTempEscrito();
                 ...
                entityManager.persist(currentAclaracion);
                generarDocumento(currentAclaracion, conjunto, usuario);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ejbContext.setRollbackOnly();
                throw new RollbackSajgException();

            }
        }


    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY)
        private void generarDocumento(AclaracionesTempEscrito findAclaracion,
                ConjuntoCertificaciones conjunto, Usuario usuario)
                throws RollbackException {
    ...
    Query actualizaCertificacionesAclaracion = entityManager
                        .createNamedQuery("Certificacion.updateCertificacionAclaraciones");
                actualizaCertificacionesAclaracion
                        .setParameter("pendienteGeneracion", true)
                        .setParameter("idAclaracion", findAclaracion.getId())
                        .setParameter("paso", paso).executeUpdate();

        }
    }
```

It suppose that I will execute commit when `guardarRequerimiento` method ends but when I execute my `nativeQuery` with `executeUpdate` I get an exception of `ConstraintViolation`

> org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement

I think that it is because although `findAclaracion.getId()` exists in the transaction, it does not exist in database and the `executeUpdate` need that this object exist in database because is not in my persistence context when execute.

Why do I get this behaviour? How can I solve?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to refresh this object after flush and before generarDocumento(currentAclaracion, conjunto, usuario); 
or
you can do it as query and loop that objectList updating values..

Comment: When I do a flush everything is fine except If executeUpdate actualizaCertificacionesAclaracion throw an exception because I try to do a rollback but It have not effect, already It is in DB. By other hand if I do not do a flush I get ConstraintViolation as I say on my post.